# I have a problem when trying to run react using Vite on default port

Tags: reactjs, https, port, vite

I'm trying to rewrite my old react project that was created using create-react-app.
I'm trying remake it using Vite.

the problem arises when I try to start the project on the default port :80.

I specified the port in the config file like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import mkcert from "vite-plugin-mkcert";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    https: true,
    host: "exampleSite.com",
    port: 80,
    strictPort: true,
  },
  plugins: [react(), mkcert()],
});
```

but the I only get response from the browser if I type in "https://exampleSite.com:80" and not just "https://exampleSite.com"

any ideas why? am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https traffic is defaultly routed to port 443.

you're trying to use port 80, the default port for http traffic.